# C# Lambda expression syntax: are brackets necessary?

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda

I'm new in C# and earlier I saw the lambda expression is like

```
(params) => { expression; }
```

but in LINQ, I saw examples like

```
IEnumerable<string> customerFirstNames = customers.Select(cust => cust.FirstName);
```

No brackets.

(I actually mean both `{}` and `()` - regardless if we call them braces, parenthesis, or brackets.)

Are they the same or is there any difference?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean braces, brackets or both? Many interpretations- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket Argument list, code body, or both (the entire expression?

Comment: `{ }` are braces, `( )` are parenthesis, and `[ ]` are brackets (in programming parlance).

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear about the different meanings of the words braces, parenthesis, and brackets. I actually meant both {} and ()

Comment: {} are braces, () are brackets, [] are square brackets, at least in the UK. I have never, ever heard anyone call () parentheses in real life - probably another horrific Americanism :'(. Edit: just noticed BIDMAS vs PEDMAS.

Comment: @Callum - to be fair, I usually call them "parens" because "parenthesis" just doesn't really roll off the tongue very smoothly. :)

Comment: {} are open-stache and close-stache. Because they look like mustaches and it's far less confusing when you call them that. :)

Comment: @Callum 'parentheses' has been used to refer to () since before the US existed. The Oxford English Dictionary even supplies variant pronunciations for both US and UK, which they likely wouldn't do for an Americanism.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The rules are:

A lambda expression has the form

```
( modifier type parameter, modifier type parameter ...) => { statements }
```

Let's consider the left side first.

The modifier can be ref, out or nothing at all.

If there are no ref or out modifiers then all the types can be elided. If there are *any* ref or out modifiers then *every* parameter declaration must have a declared type. If *any* paramter has a declared type then *every* parameter must have a declared type. So you can elide the types provided that (1) there are no refs or outs, and (2) you elide *all* of them. Otherwise, you must provide all the types.

If there is exactly *one* parameter and its type has been elided then the parentheses around the parameter list may optionally be elided also.

That's all the rules about parameter lists.  The rules about the right side are:

if the statement list consists of a single return statement with an expression:

```
x => { return x + 1; }
```

then the braces, return keyword and semicolon may be elided:

```
x => x + 1
```

furthermore, if the statement list consists of a single statement that is a statement expression:

```
x => { x++; } // Not returning the value of x++; only useful for the side effects
x => { new Y(x); } // weird! executing a ctor only for its side effects! But legal!
x => { M(x); } // note, not returning the value of M(x) even if there is one.
```

then it is also legal to elide the braces and semicolon:

```
x => x++
x => new Y(x)  
x => M(x)
```

Note that these now potentially mean something different to the reader! Before we were clearly *discarding* the return values; now the lambdas will be read as *returning* them.

*Note that this means it is legal to do this trick with void returning methods*. This is actually legal:

```
x => Console.WriteLine(x)
```

Yuck. **Don't do that.** If you mean

```
x => { Console.WriteLine(x); }
```

then say that instead. The former looks too much like you are trying to say

```
x => { return Console.WriteLine(x); }
```

which of course would be illegal.

Comment: +1 for putting braces around void-returning methods. I'd go so far as to say that if the main purpose of calling the method is to create a side-effect, put it in braces so that it looks more statementy.

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: would this mean that you would consider someone writing a method taking an Expression<Action> is doing something which encourages poor coding? Not that I've ever done it but the question popped into my head when I wrote this.

Comment: I agree with @ShuggyCoUk. The "yucky" lambda `x => Console.WriteLine(x)` can be converted to an `Expression<Action<string>>`, for example, while `x => { Console.WriteLine(x); }` cannot. An example where expression trees of "void" expressions are used, is with setup of mocks where it can be relevant to setup methods of return type `void`. Like `myMock.Setup(x => x.Initialize())`.

Answer (score 17):

Which brackets are you talking about? `(` `)` or `{` `}`?

---

`(` `)` are used in the parameter list and are required when you have more than one parameter:

```
(a, b, c) => ...
```

You can omit them when you have only one argument:

```
a => ...
```

---

`{` `}` allow you to put a block of **statements** in the body of lambda expressions:

```
(a, b, c) => {
                 Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                 Console.WriteLine("a = {0}", a);
                 Console.WriteLine("b = {0}", b);
                 Console.WriteLine("c = {0}", c);
                 return a * b + c;
             }
```

Without them, the body of a lambda expression is an **expression**:

```
(a, b, c) => a * b + c
```

Comment: You're example talks about braces rather than brackets?

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You only need brackets if you have multiple parameters.

**Update** (As is customary on SO when answers are edited after other people have answered...)

Using brackets (parenthesis "( )" and braces "{ }") is this case are redundant. The statements are equivalent. A Visual Studio add-in like ReSharper will point redundancies like this out:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/